# How to construct a linear mixed model for GWAS with SSR markers?

Tags: mixed-model, gwas

I would like to construct a linear mixed model using SSR markers. I have the phenotype vector, SSR marker matrix, and the covariance matrix for the random effect (used to control the population structure). In the mixed model, an SSR marker would be treated as a factor. How could I construct this model with R?