# Why did I get inconsistent result from ANOVA and wald test

Tags: anova, categorical-data, wald-test

I tested the effect of one factor X on my response Y. The factor has four levels A, B, C, and D and the null hypothesis I want to test is A=B=C=D.

```
# my dataset
mydata = data.frame(res=c(5,3,1,2,5,2,6,2),fac = c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D"))

# 1. using ANOVA
anova(lm(mydata$res~mydata$fac))

# output
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: mydata$res
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
mydata$fac  3    8.5  2.8333  0.7556 0.5742
Residuals   4   15.0  3.7500   


# 2. using Wald test
library("aod")
lr = summary(lm(mydata$res~mydata$fac))
wald.test(Sigma = (lr$cov.unscaled), b= (lr$coefficients)[,1], Terms = 2:4)
# output
Wald test:
----------

Chi-squared test:
X2 = 8.5, df = 3, P(> X2) = 0.037
```

As you can see, although both test the same null hypothesis, the p-value from ANOVA is 0.5742 while the p-value from the wald test is 0.037. I am not sure if my calculation process is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `wald.test()` function incorrectly (you should also mention what package the `wald.test` function is in since it's not in base R). You need to supply it with the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients and the residual degrees of freedom. These are both in the `lm` object but not the `summary.lm` object. Here's how you can get the same results using both methods:

```
fit <- lm(mydata$res ~ mydata$fac)
wald.test(Sigma = vcov(fit), b = coef(fit), Terms = 2:4, df = fit$df.residual)

## Wald test:
## ----------
##
## Chi-squared test:
## X2 = 2.3, df = 3, P(> X2) = 0.52
##
## F test:
## W = 0.76, df1 = 3, df2 = 4, P(> W) = 0.57
```

You need to supply an argument to `df` to get the F-test results. Doing otherwise only produces the Chi-square results, which are only valid in large samples.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Your answer also helps me figure out another question posted by me. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461365/how-to-construct-a-linear-mixed-model-for-gwas-with-ssr-markers

Comment: An alternative one is to calculate the Wald statistics with the formula "t(coef(fit)[2:4]) %*% solve(vcov(fit)[2:4,2:4], coef(fit)[2:4])" and then apply pchisq(2.3, df=3, lower.tail=T) in case df$residual is difficult to obtain in some complicated model